# How to let python use a varaible as an list item indicator

Tags: python, database

```
def enable_or_disable(value, user_id):
    user = User.select().where(User.user_id == user_id).get()
    if user.weekly
        user.weekly = True
```

I have this code and i want to use the feild specified in "value" instead of "weekly".
But if i would change it to user.value, it would try tor refer to the field "value". But i want it to access the field with the name of the value of the var "value".

EDIT:

```
def enable_or_disable(value, user_id):
    user = User.select().where(User.user_id == user_id).get()
    if getattr(user, value) is False:
        setattr(user, value, True)
        print(getattr(user, value))
    else:
        setattr(user, value, False)
        print(getattr(user, value))
    user.save()
...
enable_or_disable("weekly", update.effective_user.id)
```

Thsi still wont work. It always prints out false and if i look at the sqlite db its always one

Comment: This smells like bad design, but it can be done: `if getattr(user, value): setattr(user, value, True)`

Comment: How would you do it else?

Comment: And what datatype must value be? A normal string?

Comment: If it always prints `False`, it's probably always going into `else`. Many things could go wrong. You have to debug it. BTW, never do `if something is False`. Do `if not something` instead. And about "How would you do it else" - I don't know what you are doing which makes you think you need this kind of function, but there is probably a better solution for whatever you are doing.